# Can't run puma in daemon mode in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, daemon, puma

I have a rails5 app and using puma as it's web service. It's all right when to deploy it in a normal environment but failed when to deploy it in docker with daemon mode. I'll list what I can do and what I cannot do as below:

**Can:**

`rails s` without docker

`puma` without docker

`puma --daemon` without docker

`puma -C config/puma.rb` without docker # in which set daemon: true

`puma` in docker

**Can't:**

`puma --daemon' in docker

`puma -C config/puma.rb` in docker  in which set daemon: true

---

The conclusion is that I can't run puma in docker with daemon mode, and when I use `docker-compose up` command it returns:

> Puma starting in single mode...
>
> - Version 3.8.2 (ruby 2.4.0-p0), codename: Sassy Salamander
> - Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
> - Environment: production
> - Daemonizing...
> - website_1 exited with code 0

No any other informations.

So, what does it really happen?

Comment: Why do you want to deploy it in daemon mode? Docker needs a process in the foreground to continue running the container, if there is none (such as in the case of a daemonized process) then it will exit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docker containers run a single process. When that process completes, the container exits. Knowing this, let's take a look at what `puma --daemon` option does.

The help output for Puma says:

> -d, --daemon Daemonize the server into the background

When you do this, Puma is forking itself into the background. The parent process at this point is done and exits. This is the actual process that Docker knows about. Since this process is done and exits, the container exits.

To run Puma in a container you need to run in the foreground without the daemon option.

Edit: I found a good explanation of how the `Process.daemon` method works in Ruby (which Puma is using at https://github.com/puma/puma/blob/f5f23aaac7aaccff1b6b138d93dd4b1755ebf1c2/lib/puma/daemon_ext.rb) in https://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766093-daemon-processes-in-ruby.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: And how I daemonize the container running the `rails server!`?